# How do I copy files into an existing JAR with Ant?

Tags: ant, jar

I have a project that needs to access resources within its own JAR file.  When I create the JAR file for the project, I would like to copy a directory into that JAR file (I guess the ZIP equivalent would be "adding" the directory to the existing ZIP file).  I only want the copy to happen after the JAR has been created (and I obviously don't want the copy to happen if I clean and delete the JAR file).

Currently the build file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="foobar" basedir=".." default="jar">

    <!-- project-specific properties -->
    <property name="project.path" value="my/project/dir/foobar" />

    <patternset id="project.include">
        <include name="${project.path}/**" />
    </patternset>
    <patternset id="project.jar.include">
        <include name="${project.path}/**" />
    </patternset>

    <import file="common-tasks.xml" />

    <property name="jar.file" location="${test.dir}/foobar.jar" />    
    <property name="manifest.file" location="misc/foobar.manifest" />
</project>
```

Some of the build tasks are called from another file (common-tasks.xml), which I can't display here.

Comment: Why don't you just add the resources at the time you create the JAR file?  That's what I do in builds where I have JAR files that include non-code resources inside them.

Comment: Because the task that is defined for creating the JAR file is defined in another file that I can't change.

Comment: That would do it!  Oh well.  I'm glad others answered in ways that solve your problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Jar/Ear Ant tasks are subtasks of the more general [Zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html).  This means that you can also use `zipfileset` in your Jar task:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="...">
    <zipfileset dir="${project.path}" includes="*.jar" prefix="libs"/>
</jar>
```

I've also seen that you define a separate manifest file for inclusion into the Jar.  You can also use a nested `manifest` command:

```
<jar destfile="@{destfile}" basedir="@{basedir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Built-By" value="..."/>
        <attribute name="Built-Date" value="..."/>

        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="..."/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="..."/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="..."/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
<jar update="true">
...
</jar>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what actually goes in the "..."

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use the Ant tasks:

1. [Unzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) - to explode the Jar is a temp folder
2. [Copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) - to copy the folder that you want to the temp folder, and
3. [Jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) - with 'update' set to true, to package the temp folder back to the original jar file.

The Ant [Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) has examples of how to do it.

Comment: I'd like to avoid this method if possible. I've seen a way to do what I want, but I can't recall the details.