# Is there a way in ANT to extract one class file from a JAR and put it in another JAR?

Tags: ant, jar

My ANT build script uses a WebSphere command called createEJBStubs that produces a JAR file with everything plus one new generated class, namely: `com/myapp/services/_User_Service_Stub.class`.

Since this stub class is only used for running JUnit tests at dev time, I would like it to be in its own JAR file.

How can I tell ANT to copy everything in `AAA.JAR` that matches, say, `_*Stub.class` and copy only those files into `BBB.JAR` (also, maintaining the same directory/package structure)?

Any ideas or pointers would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thanks,

Rob

Comment: Possible duplicate. See [How do I copy files into an existing JAR with Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518207/how-do-i-copy-files-into-an-existing-jar-with-ant) as well as [ant : jar and zipfileset - copy files from one JAR into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837073/ant-jar-and-zipfileset-copy-files-from-one-jar-into-another).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok -- answering my own question -- that was surprisingly easy.  Sorry I asked.

```
<unzip src="AAA.JAR" dest="./temp">
  <patternset>
    <include name="**/_*Stub.class" />
  </patternset>
</unzip>

<zip destfile="BBB.JAR" basedir="./temp" />
```

Thanks ANT.

Comment: Did you try answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837073/ant-jar-and-zipfileset-copy-files-from-one-jar-into-another - that avoids unzip.