# How to set classpath in ant correctly?

Tags: java, ant

I have my single dependency on path `projectRoot/lib/jsoup.jar`.

My build.xml is simple:

```
<project name="Ant-Demo" default="main" basedir=".">

    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="buildDirectory" />
    <property name="dist.dir" value="dist" />
    <property name="docs.dir" value="docs" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />

    <path id="build.classpath">
        <pathelement location="lib/jsoup-1.7.3.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean,makedir">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/AntDemo,jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="ant.test" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
    ...........................................
```

This doesn't work, because jsoup.jar is not included in final AntDemo.jar.

**EDIT**
When compile target is running the output has warning:

```
compile:
    [javac] D:\Software\es_ws\AntDemo\build.xml:30: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to D:\Software\es_ws\AntDemo\buildDirectory
```

What does this warning mean?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to create an executable jar by including a "Class-Path" entry in your jar's manifest. For an example see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143567/cannot-find-main-class-in-file-compiled-with-ant/3144290#3144290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile classes and specify a classpath, the classes and other resources in that `javac` classpath don't get copied over to the destination, in ant or in typical command line `javac`. You need to copy them over manually, or in ant with a `copy` or other means.

Comment: <zipfileset should be used as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518207/how-do-i-copy-files-into-an-existing-jar-with-ant)

Comment: @Volodia A warning is not always critical. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103384/ant-warning-includeantruntime-was-not-set

Answer (score 2):

If you need that the content of  jsoup.jar is included on your *AntDemo.jar* you can do it on several ways.
My suggestion is use this solution:

```
<jar destfile="${dist.dir}/AntDemo.jar" >
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="ant.test" />
    </manifest>
    <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />
    <zipfileset includes="**/*.class" src="lib/jsoup-1.7.3.jar" />
</jar>
```

Comment: It is good to copy extracted class files into destination jar.